# подчеркивает одинарные кавычки в vsc

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, форматирование, prettier, форматирование-кода

Пока я не решил установить расширение prettier - всё работало идеально. Но после его установки начались проблемы с форматированием, в частности с кавычками (и ещё в начале каждой строки появились стрелки, видимо, означающие табуляцию, которых раньше я не наблюдал), которые мне этот плагин меняет на двойные в абсолютно любом проекте, несмотря на то, что у меня в настройках этого плагина выставлен параметр "использовать только одинарные", и что у меня в конфиге тоже это прописано.
Решил удалить его, вернув все настройки обратно, но он, по всей видимости, бессмертный и работает, наплевав на всё. После подчистил файлы *(из %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions)*, связанные с ним, теперь он вроде как ничего мне не изменяет, но только в html форматах все одинарные кавычки помечаются волнистой линией - почему так, если я сейчас вернул всё к исходному состоянию? можно ли как-то это решить без переустановки программы? :(
[image: табуляция показывается стрелками и подчёркиваются одинарные кавычки]

Comment: Так а что за `warning` показывает VSCode, если навести? Подозреваю, что ваш линтер хочет, чтобы вы использовали двойные кавычки везде.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, понятно, что просит двойные, но почему, если такого раньше не было, может я что-то сломал этим расширением [**выводит следующее:** __The value of attribute [ rel ] must be in double quotes.(attr-value-double-quotes)__]

Comment: Какие у вас расширения установлены? Допустим HTMLHint?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, как вы метко попали... отключил его и вправду всё исправилось. но до этого он ведь работал хорошо, его как-то можно настроить? я его вроде просто когда-то скачал и забыл про него

Comment: Да, он имеет настройки `htmlhint.options` в настройках ищите. Дальше нажимаете `Edit in settings.json` и там уже в объекте мы можете выставить`"attr-value-double-quotes": false`

Comment: @OliverPatterson, огромнейшее вам спасибо, утром на это напоролся, так взбесился... большое спасибо

Comment: Лучше потратьте время и настройте хорошо линтер и приведите свой код к единому целому!)

Comment: @OliverPatterson, та да, уж думаю стоит :)